# Como aplicar formatação de String no DataGrid - WPF

Tags: wpf

Tenho um Data Grid em WPF que tem colunas de CPF, RG, CEP e outros, preciso fazer a formatação para:

CPF: 111.111.111-11

RG: 11.111.111-1 Com numero no final

RG: 11.111.111-A Com letra no final

CEP: 11111-11

Apenas preenche os dados e não formata.

```
<Window x:Class="ProjSistema.Wpf.Cadastro.Teste"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Teste" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid  Name="dtgTeste" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="CPF" MinWidth="100" Binding="  {Binding CPF, StringFormat={}{0:###.###.###-##}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RG" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding RG, StringFormat={}{0:##.###.###-#}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="CEP" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding CEP, StringFormat={}{0:#####-##}}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class Teste : Window
{
    public Teste()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<PropriedadeTeste> lstTeste = new List<PropriedadeTeste>();
        PropriedadeTeste propTeste = new PropriedadeTeste();
        propTeste.CPF = "11111111111";
        propTeste.RG = "111111111";
        propTeste.CEP = "11111111";
        lstTeste.Add(propTeste);
        dtgTeste.ItemsSource = lstTeste;
    }
}
```

Comment: Até aonde você chegou? As colunas já estão sendo preenchidas com os dados e só falta formatar ou nem isto está acontecendo ainda?

Comment: Já estão sendo preenchidas, falta somente formatar para ficar mais agradável para os usuários.

Answer (score 1):

Dá para aplicar o [StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) ao Binding desta forma:

```
<DataGrid  Name="dtgTeste" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CPF" Binding="{Binding CPF, StringFormat={}{0:###.###.###-##}}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="RG" Binding="{Binding RG, StringFormat={}{0:##.###.###-#}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CEP" Binding="{Binding CEP, StringFormat={}{0:#####-##}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Existe também outros métodos [criando uma classe customizada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290921/how-to-set-binding-stringformat-to-all-datagridtextcolumn-controls) para fazer a formatação.

Comment: Ele não formatou eu coloquei o código acima de como estou fazendo. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Baseicamente você vai criar uma classe ou struct que contenha os dados que queira vincular ao datagrid e essa classe será responsável por receber e formatar os dados (já que esse tipo de dado não pode ser formatado)

(no exemplo abaixo formato um campo `TimeSpan` em Texto com valores em `mm:ss` e seu correspondente em base centesimal (total de minutos)

```
public class InformacaoGridMeio: ViewModelBase
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int Execucao { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TempoExecucaoTime { get; set; }
    public string TempoExecucao  => TempoExecucaoTime != TimeSpan.Zero
            ? $"{TempoExecucaoTime.Minutes:00}:{TempoExecucaoTime.Seconds:00} ({TempoExecucaoTime.TotalMinutes:00.00})"
            : "--:-- (--,--)";
}
```

Depois de criar essa classe crie sua propriedade na ViewModel e essa propriedade é que será vinculada DataGrid

```
public ObservableCollection<InformacaoGridMeio> DataGridMeio
    {
        get { return _gridMeio; }
        set { _gridMeio = value; OnPropertyChanged("DataGridMeio"); }
    }


<DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          SelectionMode="Single"  
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridMeio}" 
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faz um converter amigo.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="CPF" MinWidth="100" Binding="  {Binding CPF, Converter={StaticResource NationalRegistrationConverter}}"/>
```

segue o converter que uso.

```
/// <summary>
/// Valida um texto para ver se é um CNPJ ou CPF
/// </summary>
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(String))]
public class NationalRegistrationValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converte o valor para o bindind de um objeto source
    /// </summary>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Se não estiver vazio         
        if (value != null)
        {
            // Variaveis
            string OldValue = ((string)value).ToString().Trim();
            string NewValue = "";

            // Se tiver 10 caracteres
            if (OldValue.Length == 11)
            {
                // Recebe o valor formatado
                NewValue = OldValue.Insert(3, ".").Insert(7, ".").Insert(11, "-"); ;
            }
            // Se tiver 11 caracteres
            else if (OldValue.Length == 14)
            {
                // Recebe o valor formatado
                NewValue = OldValue.Insert(2, ".").Insert(6, ".").Insert(10, "/").Insert(15, "-");
            }

            // Retorna o novo valor
            return NewValue;
        }

        // Retorna o valor que veio
        return value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converte o valor do binding devolta para o objeto source
    /// </summary>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Se nao estiver vazio
        if (value != null)
        {
            // Recebe o valor sem os caracteres especiais
            string OldValue = value.ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty).Replace("/", "").Replace(".", "");

            // Retorna o valor em decimal
            return OldValue;
        }

        // Retorna o valor
        return value;
    }
}
```

não esqueça de declarar no recurso da sua window ou control o converter.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <control:NationalRegistrationValueConverter x:Key="NationalRegistrationConverter"/>    
</Window.Resources>
```